# Chrome Extension Override new tab and show random html page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

I wonder if it is possible to have any random html page from a defined selection as new overridden tab page? ([Overriding Chrome pages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/override/))

I do not mean any external pages likes twitter or facebook, but my own. I'd be happy for some ideas as I have to define one page inside the manifest.json.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: No, you'll have to change the contents of the page yourself or redirect to another URL in your code.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so i really cannot choose from a random page a.html, b.html, c.html from within my index.html? a shame :(

Comment: @wOxxOm isn't the unsplash chrome extension showing a random html page? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unsplash-instant/pejkokffkapolfffcgbmdmhdelanoaih

Comment: No, it uses the same index.html. You can use crxviewer to inspect it.